# Internal form mapping is undefined for "task1"

Tags: bonita

I'm trying to build a simple process,
I've created the process, a form for the the pool and the human task: 
"clicked on the pool -> application -> PageFlow -> Add" and 
"clicked on the human Task -> application -> PageFlow -> Add"

But I'm facing this error:

> Internal form mapping is undefined for Étape1.
>       org.bonitasoft.studio.designer.core.bar.FormMappingBarResourceProvider.isValid(FormMappingBarResourceProvider.java:147)
>       org.bonitasoft.studio.designer.core.bar.FormMappingBarResourceProvider.addFormMapping(FormMappingBarResourceProvider.java:83)
>       org.bonitasoft.studio.designer.core.bar.FormMappingBarResourceProvider.newFormMappingModel(FormMappingBarResourceProvider.java:76)
>       org.bonitasoft.studio.designer.core.bar.FormMappingBarResourceProvider.addResourcesForConfiguration(FormMappingBarResourceProvider.java:68)
>       org.bonitasoft.studio.engine.export.BarExporter.createBusinessArchive(BarExporter.java:117)
>       org.bonitasoft.studio.engine.export.BarExporter.createBusinessArchive(BarExporter.java:91)
>       org.bonitasoft.studio.engine.export.BarExporter.createBusinessArchive(BarExporter.java:165)
>       org.bonitasoft.studio.engine.operation.ExportBarOperation.exportBar(ExportBarOperation.java:118)
>       org.bonitasoft.studio.engine.operation.ExportBarOperation.run(ExportBarOperation.java:106)
>       org.bonitasoft.studio.engine.ui.wizard.ExportBarWizardPage$7.run(ExportBarWizardPage.java:405)
>       org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)

Comment: Can you indicate which version of Bonita BPM are you using? Also if you can share you process diagram (i.e. export and share the .bos file) that can help to reproduce and figure out the cause of the issue. Thanks.

Comment: here is the link to download the .bos file

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9bJ8Xhwhc_ZaEU3NERDaDBPcXc/view?usp=sharing

I'm using BonitaBPMCommunity-7.0.1
Thanks

Comment: actually, by application, I meant  "6.x Application".
This allows to design forms with the former designer. But with version 7, I should go in "execution" > "(instantiation) form" instead to use the new designer.
Problem resolved,
Thank you